# How to create a Makefile for java with multiple files directories

Tags: java, class, makefile, javac

I'am trying to create a Makefile to compile a project in Java, I maked the project with NetBeans but i need to creat the .jar by the  terminal.
The directory estructure is this:

```
Project/src/domain
Project/src/domain/controllers
Project/src/domain/controllers/drivers
Project/src/presentation
Project/src/persistence
```

In all that directories i have .java but i want to make a `Project/bin/clases` folder where to save al the .class.
Tha Main class is `Project/src/presentation/Main.java`

Can anyone helpme to find a way to compile this project with Makefile ?

Comment: You should strongly consider using something like `ant` or `maven` instead of `make`.

Comment: Agree with BadZen.  Java and make do not mix, mainly because the names of the generated files are not always directly related to the names of the input files (like in C-type languages which compile foo.c into foo.o etc.)  Make really relies on these types of naming conventions.

Comment: but my university teacher needs a makefile to compile and make  . jar automatically,  normally I use NetBeans and do all the compiling thinks

Comment: this is why you should use gradle wrapper, which is small bat and sh file generated by gradle and can be freely distributed everywhere without need gradle to be installed on given machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: Sorry, I forget to tell the solution, I just maked a Makefile adding linux intructions with the following content:

```
default:
    javac -d EXE src/presentation/*.java src/data/*.java src/domain/controllers/*.java
runMain: default
    java -cp EXE presentation.Main
jar: default
    cd EXE; jar cfe run.jar presentation.Main .;mv run.jar ..
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, the best thing you can do is to use some build tool like `gradle` or `maven`. I suggest gradle, especially gradle wrapper.

If you're working with netbeans, see [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support)
To learn about gradle wrapper go [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

The main gradle file is `build.gradle` and the "hello world" looks like this:

```
group 'your.company'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Comment: But there is no way to create everything just with the make?  it's my university work but I don't find any way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by create everything? All files within src/main/java structure are compiled, tested, and packed into jar after running `gradlew build` command. Still you can customize the source file set if you truly need to be different like: src/domain/controllers etc..